# How to add a console command to nitro build

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I'm currently building a Nuxt3 app and I need to deploy it as a Node.js server. When built, I receive a nice and tidy `.output/server/index.mjs` that I can run from my Docker image.

However, I also need several console commands to import/export database dumps and perform other maintenance operations with the deployed app.

For example, I want to be able to run on the server something like `node server/migrate.mjs my-migration.sql`

How do I add them so they're built and available inside the .output folder? I could concievably build them as a separate package or project but there must be a better solution.